# How can I change the latex source to obtain undivided pages?

Tags: two-column

The template of the journal contains a command that divided each page into two, which means each page contains two pages. I need to change that to normal, I did not find any solution on the internet, please find attached the code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{NSP1}
\usepackage{url,floatflt}
\usepackage{helvet,times}
\usepackage{psfig,graphics}
\usepackage{mathptmx,amsmath,amssymb,bm}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[bf,hypcap]{caption}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\tolerance=1
\emergencystretch=\maxdimen
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\hbadness=10000

\topmargin=0.00cm

\def\sm{\smallskip}
\def\no{\noindent}

\def\firstpage{1}
\setcounter{page}{\firstpage}
\def\thevol{7}
\def\thenumber{?}
\def\theyear{2022}

\begin{document}

\titlefigurecaption{{\large \bf \rm Information Sciences Letters }\\ {\it\small An International Journal}}

\title{Reflection and transmission of an incident
progressive wave by obstacles in homogeneous
shallow water}

\author{***\hyperlink{author1}{$^1$}, Mohamed A. Helal \hyperlink{author2}{$^2$} and Moustafa S. Abou-Dina \hyperlink{author3}{$^3$}}
\institute{$^1$ Department of Mathematics, .\\
$^2$Department of Mathematics, Faculty of Science, Cairo University, Egypt.}

\titlerunning{progressive wave by obstacles in homogeneous
shallow water}
\authorrunning{ K. Al Arfaj, M. A. Helal and M. S. Abou-Dina}

%corresponding author email
\mail{ka}

\received{...}
\revised{...}
\accepted{...}
\published{...}

\abstracttext{The influence  of a  suspended fixed  obstacle  on  an  incident  progressive  wave  inside  an  ideal  homogeneous  shallow  water is studied in  two dimensions.  The  fluid  occupies  an  infinite  channel  of a constant  depth, and  a  fixed obstacle of a  small  horizontal extent is partially submerged without contact with the bottom of the channel.   An asymptotic double series  expansion  for the solution is used.   The  procedure enables  us  to calculate .}

\keywords{Progressive wave, shallow water, reflection, fixed obstacle}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
Simulations for the geophysical phenomena of a fluid flow over weirs, under gates and submerged elands were studied in several theoretical and experimental works. These works deal with model problems of free-surface fluid flow over a topography or under floating submerged bodies. the theoretical problem is a
nonlinear boundary value problem which may be in certain cases, constrained by initial conditions (see \cite{ABWZ,1}).

The two-dimensional fluid flow over an obstacle or under a floating body, within the frame of the linearized theory of motion, has been investigated by several authors, for instance \cite{2,3,4,5}. The mathematical theory used in these investigations is inadequate to describe the important nonlinear aspects of the phenomenon. Using a certain procedure the solution for the velocity potential of the nonlinear problem is expressed as a power series in a certain small parameter \cite{1}. The above-mentioned linearized theory assumes the first term of such a series as a first approximation of the solution. the radius of convergence of this series is shown by Gouyon \cite{6} to be of the same order as that of the ratio of the free surface amplitude to the wave length. Hence, this theory is inadequate to deal with the propagation of long waves.

Different numerical techniques were developed to solve the nonlinear system of equations to which the original problem is reduced. Yeung \cite{7} present an exhaustive review of the numerical techniques which are widely applied to this system.

Analytical techniques, within the frame of the shallow-water theory, were used by several authors to investigate free-surface flows over certain non-horizontal bottoms, see \cite{8,9,10}.
 
Guli \cite{8} and Abou-dina and Helal \cite{10} studied the problem of the reflection and transmission of an incident progressive wave over a topography in shallow water using both of the Lagrangean an Eulerian description of the problem, respectively.

In the present work, we investigate the effect of a fixed vertical submerged barrier on the propagation of an incident wave inside a homogeneous fluid. Euler’s description is used and the problem is studied within the frame of the two-dimensional shallow water theory. The fluid is supposed to occupy an infinite channel of constant depth and the horizontal extent of the submerged barrier
is assumed to be small, see fig. \eqref{fig1}.

The analysis enables to separate progressive waves from local perturbations and shows the absence of reflected waves in the first order of approximation. These results are similar to those obtained for the case of nonhorizontal topograpgy by Ogilvie \cite{3}, Guli \cite{8} and Abou-Dina and Helal \cite{10}. The second order approximation of the solution is found to be the superposition of progressive wave and local perturbations. Analytical expressions are calculated for the local perturbations of the second order. For approximations of order higher than two, the expressions for the progressive waves contain a secular term
which increases monotonically with time and distance. This unacceptable result is due to certain aspects of the mathematical used procedure. For this reason, the procedure is modified by utilizing a suitable transformation of variables. The modification reduces the determination of the transmitted wave to be the
solution of the equation of Korteweg and de Vries ($\textbf{KdV}$).

As an illustration, the special case of the incident uniform flow is considered and the stream lines of the resulting flow are drawn.
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=20]{fig1.png}
\caption{Explanatory diagram of an upstream wave inside a fluid with a fixed immersed obstacle penetrating the free surface}
\label{fig1}
\end{figure}
The origin of the Cartesian system of coordinates is fixed in the submerged obstacle. the axis \textbf{Ox} points along the direction of the incident-wave velocity, the axis \textbf{OY} is vertical upwards and the plane \textbf{Oxz} coincides with the free surface at rest. The bottom of the channel is impermeable and horizontal
\section{Main problem}
Consider an incident upstream wave inside a fluid layer with free surface and finite depth in an infinitely long channel. The bottom of the channel is horizontal


\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{14}
    \newblock Temperville A.,
    \newblock Contribution a la theorie des ondes de gravite en eau peu profonde,
    \newblock \emph{Thesis, University of Grenoble, France}, (1985).
    
\bibitem{2}
    \newblock Ursell, F.,
    \newblock The effect of a fixed vertical barrier on surface waves in deep water,
    \newblock \emph{Math. Proc. Camb. Philos. Soc.}, (1947),\textbf{43} 374-382.
    
    \bibitem{1}
    \newblock Wehausen, J. V. and Laitone E. V.,
    \newblock Surface Waves,
    \newblock \emph{Fluid Dynamics/ Strömung- smechanik}, (1960), 446-778.
    
    \bibitem{4}
    \newblock Wiegel, R. L.,
    \newblock Transmission of waves past a rigid vertical thin barrier,
    \newblock \emph{J. Waterw. Harb.}, (1960),\textbf{86} 1-12..
    
\bibitem{7}
    \newblock Yeung, R.W.,
    \newblock Numerical methods in free surface flows,
    \newblock \emph{Ann. Rev. Fluid Mech.}, (1982),\textbf{14} 395–442.

\bibitem{15}
    \newblock Zabusky, N. J. and Kruskal, M. D.,
    \newblock Interaction of Solitons in a Collisionless
Plasma and the Recurrence of Initial States,
    \newblock \emph{Phys. Rev. Lett.}, (1965),\textbf{15} 240–243.


\end{thebibliography}


\emergencystretch=\hsize

\begin{center}
\rule{6 cm}{0.02 cm}
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you add a link to where we can get the class from?

Comment: please find attached the link to Overleaf:   https://www.overleaf.com/1648992469ypjyznzjfkbg

Comment: Are you submitting to this journal?  If so, do not change their template.  If not, why are you using their template?

Comment: I asked for their permission t change that, and they approve it, can you help with that?

Comment: I don't know how to apply it.

Comment: It is also possible to switch b;ack and forth betwen twocolumn and onecolumn formatting, albeit only at the top of a page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you edit the class file and change

```
\ExecuteOptions{final,twocolumn,fleqn,a4paper,twoside,10pt,instindent}
```

to

```
\ExecuteOptions{final,fleqn,a4paper,twoside,10pt,instindent}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `\onecolumn` to switch back to a one column layout:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{NSP1}
\usepackage{url,floatflt}
\usepackage{helvet,times}
\usepackage{psfig,graphics}
\usepackage{mathptmx,amsmath,amssymb,bm}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[bf,hypcap]{caption}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\tolerance=1
\emergencystretch=\maxdimen
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\hbadness=10000

\topmargin=0.00cm

\def\sm{\smallskip}
\def\no{\noindent}

\def\firstpage{1}
\setcounter{page}{\firstpage}
\def\thevol{7}
\def\thenumber{?}
\def\theyear{2022}

\begin{document}

\titlefigurecaption{{\large \bf \rm Information Sciences Letters }\\ {\it\small An International Journal}}

\title{Reflection and transmission of an incident
progressive wave by obstacles in homogeneous
shallow water}

\author{Kawther Al Arfaj \hyperlink{author1}{$^1$}, Mohamed A. Helal \hyperlink{author2}{$^2$} and Moustafa S. Abou-Dina \hyperlink{author3}{$^3$}}
\institute{$^1$ Department of Mathematics, College of Science, King Faisal University, P.O. Box 400,
Al-Ahsa 31982, Saudi Arabia.\\
$^2$Department of Mathematics, Faculty of Science, Cairo University, Egypt.\\
$^3$Department of Mathematics, Faculty of Science, Cairo University, Egypt.}

\titlerunning{progressive wave by obstacles in homogeneous
shallow water}
\authorrunning{ K. Al Arfaj, M. A. Helal and M. S. Abou-Dina}

%corresponding author email
\mail{kkarfaj@kfu.edu.sa}

\received{...}
\revised{...}
\accepted{...}
\published{...}

\abstracttext{The influence  of a  suspended fixed  obstacle  on  an  incident  progressive  wave  inside  an  ideal  homogeneous  shallow  water is studied in  two dimensions.  The  fluid  occupies  an  infinite  channel  of a constant  depth, and  a  fixed obstacle of a  small  horizontal extent is partially submerged without contact with the bottom of the channel.   An asymptotic double series  expansion  for the solution is used.   The  procedure enables  us  to calculate .}

\keywords{Progressive wave, shallow water, reflection, fixed obstacle}
\onecolumn
\maketitle


\section{Introduction}
Simulations for the geophysical phenomena of a fluid flow over weirs, under gates and submerged elands were studied in several theoretical and experimental works. These works deal with model problems of free-surface fluid flow over a topography or under floating submerged bodies. the theoretical problem is a
nonlinear boundary value problem which may be in certain cases, constrained by initial conditions (see \cite{ABWZ,1}).

The two-dimensional fluid flow over an obstacle or under a floating body, within the frame of the linearized theory of motion, has been investigated by several authors, for instance \cite{2,3,4,5}. The mathematical theory used in these investigations is inadequate to describe the important nonlinear aspects of the phenomenon. Using a certain procedure the solution for the velocity potential of the nonlinear problem is expressed as a power series in a certain small parameter \cite{1}. The above-mentioned linearized theory assumes the first term of such a series as a first approximation of the solution. the radius of convergence of this series is shown by Gouyon \cite{6} to be of the same order as that of the ratio of the free surface amplitude to the wave length. Hence, this theory is inadequate to deal with the propagation of long waves.

Different numerical techniques were developed to solve the nonlinear system of equations to which the original problem is reduced. Yeung \cite{7} present an exhaustive review of the numerical techniques which are widely applied to this system.

Analytical techniques, within the frame of the shallow-water theory, were used by several authors to investigate free-surface flows over certain non-horizontal bottoms, see \cite{8,9,10}.
 
Guli \cite{8} and Abou-dina and Helal \cite{10} studied the problem of the reflection and transmission of an incident progressive wave over a topography in shallow water using both of the Lagrangean an Eulerian description of the problem, respectively.

In the present work, we investigate the effect of a fixed vertical submerged barrier on the propagation of an incident wave inside a homogeneous fluid. Euler’s description is used and the problem is studied within the frame of the two-dimensional shallow water theory. The fluid is supposed to occupy an infinite channel of constant depth and the horizontal extent of the submerged barrier
is assumed to be small, see fig. \eqref{fig1}.

The analysis enables to separate progressive waves from local perturbations and shows the absence of reflected waves in the first order of approximation. These results are similar to those obtained for the case of nonhorizontal topograpgy by Ogilvie \cite{3}, Guli \cite{8} and Abou-Dina and Helal \cite{10}. The second order approximation of the solution is found to be the superposition of progressive wave and local perturbations. Analytical expressions are calculated for the local perturbations of the second order. For approximations of order higher than two, the expressions for the progressive waves contain a secular term
which increases monotonically with time and distance. This unacceptable result is due to certain aspects of the mathematical used procedure. For this reason, the procedure is modified by utilizing a suitable transformation of variables. The modification reduces the determination of the transmitted wave to be the
solution of the equation of Korteweg and de Vries ($\textbf{KdV}$).

As an illustration, the special case of the incident uniform flow is considered and the stream lines of the resulting flow are drawn.
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=20]{fig1.png}
\caption{Explanatory diagram of an upstream wave inside a fluid with a fixed immersed obstacle penetrating the free surface}
\label{fig1}
\end{figure}
The origin of the Cartesian system of coordinates is fixed in the submerged obstacle. the axis \textbf{Ox} points along the direction of the incident-wave velocity, the axis \textbf{OY} is vertical upwards and the plane \textbf{Oxz} coincides with the free surface at rest. The bottom of the channel is impermeable and horizontal
\section{Main problem}
Consider an incident upstream wave inside a fluid layer with free surface and finite depth in an infinitely long channel. The bottom of the channel is horizontal


\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{14}
    \newblock Temperville A.,
    \newblock Contribution a la theorie des ondes de gravite en eau peu profonde,
    \newblock \emph{Thesis, University of Grenoble, France}, (1985).
    
\bibitem{2}
    \newblock Ursell, F.,
    \newblock The effect of a fixed vertical barrier on surface waves in deep water,
    \newblock \emph{Math. Proc. Camb. Philos. Soc.}, (1947),\textbf{43} 374-382.
    
    \bibitem{1}
    \newblock Wehausen, J. V. and Laitone E. V.,
    \newblock Surface Waves,
    \newblock \emph{Fluid Dynamics/ Strömung- smechanik}, (1960), 446-778.
    
    \bibitem{4}
    \newblock Wiegel, R. L.,
    \newblock Transmission of waves past a rigid vertical thin barrier,
    \newblock \emph{J. Waterw. Harb.}, (1960),\textbf{86} 1-12..
    
\bibitem{7}
    \newblock Yeung, R.W.,
    \newblock Numerical methods in free surface flows,
    \newblock \emph{Ann. Rev. Fluid Mech.}, (1982),\textbf{14} 395–442.

\bibitem{15}
    \newblock Zabusky, N. J. and Kruskal, M. D.,
    \newblock Interaction of Solitons in a Collisionless
Plasma and the Recurrence of Initial States,
    \newblock \emph{Phys. Rev. Lett.}, (1965),\textbf{15} 240–243.


\end{thebibliography}


\emergencystretch=\hsize

\begin{center}
\rule{6 cm}{0.02 cm}
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

[image]